# Error in string

Tags: vb.net

Good day!

I had this problem, i created a module and in that module i put my provider as staed below:

```
Dim connString
Return "Data Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=.\..\..\sgsai.mdb"
```

now my problem is in this line of code under my form button as stated in this line of code:

```
Dim dbConnection As New OledbConnection(connString)
```

there is no error in the code but when i run it the error is in my provider. My database file is located in the same folder as my vb file. i don't understand.

Comment: Make it a shared function as a string and return the connection string...

Comment: If you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) it will point out some problems with the first part of code you showed.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're assigning anything to the `connString` variable.  It's probably null or empty.  Put a breakpoint on the line where you instantiate the `OleDbConnection` and inspect the value of `connString`.